# Insert an image into mysql which is selected from DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

There is a DataGrid with bunch of images in my wpf.
I have to select an image from my DataGrid and insert that image to mysql DB.
My code is not working properly. 
I need help. My code is below.

`private void btnImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            {
        string constr = "Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=MyCollege;User Id=root;password=2525";
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO images(Image) VALUES ('" + dataGrid1.SelectedValue + "')", con);
                con.Open();
                int s1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (s1 > 0)
                {
                    lbl1.Content = "Image inserted succesfully";
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }`

Comment: And what type in your SelectedValue? It's ImageSource? To put image in mysql you must use Parameters for MySqlCommand where you put your image in stream.

Comment: Thanks for attention. As I am new on wpf and c#, I couldn't convert selected image into byte data,and couldn't write proper query code.So specific examples would be much appreciated please. Thanks